# How do I return the head of the list in this recursive function?

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

Im makin' a program in which i got a list filled with numbers from a file and when there's a double value like 11 11 i put a number between the couple of numbers

Example List:

```
1 11 11 56 8 8 10
```

List with the number i=5 added:

```
1 11 5 11 8 5 8 10
```

so considering the linked list structed like this

```
typedef struct Snode{
    int info;
    struct Snode *link;
}Tnode;

typedef Tnode *Tlist;
```

I also tried to make the recursive function

```
Tlist InsertBtw(Tlist list,int i){
    Tnode *prec,*succ,*newnode;

    if(list==NULL)
        return NULL; //PASSO BASE   
    prec=list;
    succ=list->link;
    if(prec->info==succ->info){
        newnode=MakeNode(i);
        prec->link=newnode;
        newnode->link=succ;
        list=list->link;
        return InsertBtw(list,i);
    }
    list=InsertBtw(list->link,i);
    return list;
}
```

But something weird happens . At the last "cycle" of the recursive function when i pass the value list->link this checks the `if(list==NULL)` but this if ain't verified so it never returns NULL and it gives me error dump...something.

UPDATED

```
Tlist InsertBtw(Tlist list,int i){
    Tnode *prec,*succ,*newnode;
    if(list->link==NULL)
        return NULL;
    prec=list;succ=list->link;
    if(prec->info==succ->info){
        newnode=MakeNode(i);
        prec->link=newnode;
        newnode->link=succ;
        }
    list->link=InsertBtw(succ,i);
return list;
}
```

Now the problem is that i cut the last node and it makes no changes into the list

Comment: You need to check that `list->link` is not NULL.

Comment: last Snode have info=10 and link=NULL, so it could be possible that succ is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Barmar that's not a check it's the basic step in case the list is empty

Comment: You have to do that check before you can use `succ->info`.

Comment: If the list has only 1 element, or it has no duplicates, you'll run into that error.

Comment: in other word, last node have link attribute valued to NULL

Comment: @Lety shouldn't it be like that ? :D

Comment: Just add `if (succ == NULL)` `return list;` before the `if (prec->info == succ->info) {` line.

Comment: Does `InsertBtw` need to return a value? It's return value doesn't seem to be all that meaningful. It usually returns `NULL`. Why not set the return type to `void` and return with no value?

Comment: The function prototype was given i didn't decide that btw i made a few changes . Now it returns the head as I wanted but the program makes no changes to the list and i dont get it why tbh. check the update question

Comment: @PeriGiochi try this: `Tlist InsertBtw(Tlist list,int i){ Tnode *newnode; if(list->link==NULL) return NULL; if(list->info==list->link->info){ newnode=MakeNode(i); newnode->link=list->link; list->link=newnode; } InsertBtw(list->link,i); return list;}` it is unclear to me what you want to return, but recursion should works, bye